# second tkinter window within an imported function

Tags: python, tkinter

I have 2 `.py` files. The first file loads a Tkinter window with a button that runs `function1`. `function1` imports the second file and runs `function2` within it.

At start of function 2, I want to show a second Tkinter window and allow drop down selection of items.

It runs fine but my drop down options ('Course 1','Course 2','Course 3') on the second tk window are not appearing despite me setting them (`clicked.set("Select MOSAIQ Course")`). When drop down item is selected, it doesn't stick so the user cant see that they selected it....

File 1:

```
root = Tk()
root.title("Auto Plan Breast v" + str(script_version))
mycolour = '#%02x%02x%02x' % (50, 50, 50)
myorange = '#%02x%02x%02x' % (255, 140, 0)
root.configure(background = mycolour)
root.geometry("760x240")
######add label#######################
lbl1 = Label(root, text='This script will auto plan a Breast/Chest wall - Click on the Site/Technique you want to use')
lbl1.place(x=65, y =5)
lbl1.configure(background = mycolour, fg = "white", justify=CENTER)

def autoplanWB():
    import Whole_Breast_v4
    Whole_Breast_v4.autoplan()


myButton = Button(root, text="WHOLE BREAST Plan 26Gy/5F", command=autoplanWB)
myButton.place(x=10, y=100)
root.mainloop()
```

File 2:

```
def autoplan():
    top1 = Tk()
    top1.title("Auto Plan Breast v" + str(script_version))
    mycolour = '#%02x%02x%02x' % (50, 50, 50)
    myorange = '#%02x%02x%02x' % (255, 140, 0)
    top1.configure(background = mycolour)
    top1.geometry("760x240")
    lbl1 = Label(top1, text='Ensure you have loaded the checkers approved medial field plan.Select 
    the course, machine and clinical goals and then click Start')
    lbl1.place(x=65, y =5)
    lbl1.configure(background = mycolour, fg = "white", justify=CENTER)
        
    
    def autoWBF():
       ......

    clicked = StringVar()
    clicked.set("Select MOSAIQ Course")
    drop = OptionMenu(top1, clicked, "Course 1", "Course 2", "Course 3" )**
    drop.place(x=10, y=50)

    myButton = Button(top1, text="Start WHOLE BREAST Plan 26Gy/5F", command=autoWBF)
    myButton.place(x=10, y=100)

    top1.mainloop()
```

Comment: Don't use more than one`Tk()` object. Use a `Toplevel()` window instead.

Comment: thanks that has done the trick!cheers,